# New iOS popoverPresentationController much slower to appear than UIPopoverController

Tags: ios, performance, uipopovercontroller, popover, presentation

I've recently been updating an application to replace instances of the deprecated UIPopoverController with UIViewControllers presented modally, and when I create one, it takes about 250% as long to appear. Also, setting animated:NO in the presentViewController method also seems to have no effect.

Does anyone know why this might be?

Here's some of the relevant code I've written (it's in an IBAction from a UIButton being pressed):

```
UIViewController *popover = [[MyViewControllerForPopover alloc] initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nil];
popover.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
popover.preferredContentSize = popover.view.frame.size;
popover.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = parentView;
popover.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = location;
popover.popoverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections = arrows;
[parentViewController presentViewController:popover animated:NO completion:nil];
```

I tried setting modalTransitionStyle, but it didn't seem to have any effect on the style or duration of animation. What I see is a delay, followed by the animation, so it looks like there's an extended amount of time spent setting up the view controller.

This is the same view controller that used to be put inside the UIPopover, via the initWithContentViewController init method, so I can't understand why this is slower.

Thanks

Comment: @matt This is not true. From the documentation: "If you created the view controller but have not yet presented it, **accessing this property creates a popover presentation controller when the value in the modalPresentationStyle property is popover**. If the modal presentation style is a different value, this property is nil."

Comment: @Cloov Strange. Internally, `UIPopoverController` presents a view controller using a presentation controller. You can put breakpoint on `presentViewController:animated:completion:` and see that it is called when presenting a `UIPopoverController`.

Comment: @Cloov I got this issue too. Did you find any solution on this?